# Duplicate constructor call in assignment

Tags: c++11, constructor, stl

I am convinced my question has been already answered here in SO but I am not capable to find it. If so please mark it es duplicate - thank you!

here is the MCVE:

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>

using foo = struct foo
{
    int foo2;
    foo() { printf( "In foo contructor.\n" ); }
};

std::map<int, foo> bar;

int main()
{
    bar [1] = {};
}
```

Output:

```
In foo contructor.
In foo contructor.
```

Why is the `foo` constructor called twice? What do I have to change in order it is called only once?

Compiler: `gcc 4.9.3`

Compiler flags: `-O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator[]` already default constructs its `mapped_value`, even if you don't assign to it. Then your assignment default constructs an rvalue, which is then move assigned to the `mapped_value` at the key `1`. 
Have you taken a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace? It might do what you want to do.

Comment: OK. I see I need time till I understand the whole mechanism. With `emplace()` it works. Thx!

Comment: @AlBundy Look at the documentation of `std::map::operator[]` and `std::map::operator=` on cppreference. The articles will help you understand how and when objects are created internally in the `std::map`.

Comment: @KABoissonneault, I know one time for `bar[1]` operation, what's the other time? For `{}` to construct a `foo` object?

Comment: @BlackMamba That's right. As I've said, the expression on the right side of the assignment, `{}`, will first produce a temporary, unnamed object called an rvalue (because you usually find them on the Right side of assignments) using the default constructor (because there are no arguments in `{}`). Then, because we're assigning an rvalue, the `operator=` of `std::map` can detect that (since C++11) and move assign the `foo` object (the move `operator=` of `foo` was generated by the compiler). `emplace` on the other hand forwards the arguments (or none) and constructs the object in-place